# How to fix Stripe payments error? No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload

Tags: typescript, firebase, stripe-payments

Why am I catching this error?

I've seen similar questions here, but they don't seem to fix my issue.

Error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing

Here is my index.ts with keys removed.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

import * as Stripe from 'stripe';
const stripe = new Stripe('sk_test_*****************************');
const endpointSecret = 'whsec_******************************';

import * as express from 'express';
import * as cors from 'cors';


const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express();
app.use(cors({origin: true}));


app.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}), async(req, res) => {

  const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'] as string;
  let event;

    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.body, sig, endpointSecret);
    } catch (err) {

      console.log("ERROR!!!1");
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
    }

    console.log('Success:', event.id);

    // Handle the checkout.session.completed event
    if (event.type === 'checkout.session.completed') {

      const session = event.data.object;
      console.log("MADE IT!!!");
      console.log(session);
      return;

      // Fulfill the purchase...
      //handleCheckoutSession(session);
    }

    return;

});

export const payments = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: This could be a similar question with an accepted solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56146244/4957620

Answer (score 17):

In my case it occurred because I was using wrong "Signing secret". I was using the webhook id which appears at the top right corner. But we have to use "**Signing secret**"

So to get it please follow the following steps:

1. Login to Stripe dashboard.
2. Go to Developers->Webhooks.
3. Click on your webhook.
4. Search for "Signing secret".
5. Click "Reveal".
6. Then use it in your code.

It solved my issue. Please try it. As the UI of the stripe changed so most of us gets lost in this.

Comment: Is'nt this working only for live environment. What about testing on the local?

Answer (score 9):

2021 - Solution

I faced that error, and after a lot research I could not figure out the problem easily, but finally I could do it based in my architecture below:

```
//App.js

this.server.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.originalUrl.startsWith('/webhook')) {
    next();
  } else {
    express.json()(req, res, next);
  }
});
```

```
//routes.js

routes.post(
  '/webhook-payment-intent-update',
  bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/json' }),

  //your stripe logic (Im using a controller, but wherever)
  (req, res) => {
    stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(...)
  }
)
```

**Two big warnings to pay attention:**

- Make sure to send the `req.headers['stripe-signature']`
- Make sure that your `endpointSecret` is right, if not it will still saying the same error

**Tips:**

- Test it locally by installing the Stripe CLI: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/test
- Verify your key on stripe dashboard or you can also make sure if you have the right key by verifying you stripe log as below:

[image: webhook secret key example]

Comment: bodyParser.anything is depdeprecated use **express.raw({ type: "application/json" })** instead

Answer (score 2):

This error message is also thrown if the signing secret is incorrect. If you ensure you are passing the raw body, double check your secret and that it is correct.

I received this error when I revisited (after a couple of months) a side project I was working on that required a Stripe integration. The error was because they rotated my signing secret after 90 days. Per their customer service they don't send a notification when they rotate their keys so it was not very apparent.

Comment: Thank you! This resolved the issue I was facing. It would be great if they informed you that they had rotated the signing secret.

Answer (score -2):

`req.body` is the parsed JSON body. You will want `req.rawBody.toString()` instead, which should verify.

Comment: Thanks. That gives me the error: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I also had to change it to req.body.rawBody.toString() as req.rawBody.toString()  gave me this error: Property 'rawBody' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any>'.

Comment: Try req.rawBody do not add toString()

Comment: req.rawBody gives me the error: Property 'rawBody' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any>'. as

Comment: Hmm, `req.rawBody` may be getting lost since you're routing an Express app through. It will be on the original incoming `req` in the `onRequest()`, so you may need to find a way to pipe that through to your express app. See [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_content_types) for more about rawBody.